# Why it says the `hover:` class does not exist. If `hover:` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am new in front-end development, and I try to build new react-tailwindcss project. My project throw error like "The `hover:` class does not exist. If `hover:` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.", any idea?

**global.css:**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer components {
.icon{
    @apply hidden xl:inline-flex p-2 h-10 w-10 bg-gray-200 rounded-full text-gray-700 
cursor-pointer hover: bg-gray-300; 
}

.inputIcon{
    @apply  flex items-center space-x-1 hover: bg-gray-100
    flex-grow justify-center p-2 rounded-xl cursor-pointer ;
}
}
```

Comment: did you install package for tailwind-css

Comment: @Skysoft13, yes I do :)

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between "hover:" and the style. For example, `hover: bg-gray-100` should be `hover:bg-gray-100`

Comment: @CraigE, tnx so much :)

Answer (score 37):

Remove space after **hover:**

There should not be any space before or after : (colon) in hover. IDE generally adds space for formatting which causes this problem.

```
hover:bg-gray-300
```

> **Tip** I have same issue save without format on visual studio code
> `ctrl + k` `then ctrl + shift + s`

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I copied and pasted code and there was a colon `:` after `@apply` i.e.

```
.toggle-checkbox:checked {
  @apply: bg-primary;      // error due to ':' after @apply
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue. You just need to delete space between colon(:) and the text

ex:

```
hover: bg-gray-300;

hover:bg-gray-300; //error fixed
```

Answer (score 2):

The choice of **Document Formatter** will cause this problem. I experienced it when I changed my Default Document Formatter from Prettier to CSS Language Features.

I just reverted my changes back to Prettier as the Default CSS Document Formatter. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

there's a space between Hover: and bg-gray-300 remove it and it will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Already Raised on GitHub

Tailwind doesn't currently support `@apply`ing classes that contain responsive or state prefixes.
It's described in more detail in the `@apply` [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply).

[Similar issue raised on GitHub](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/208)
Useful reply from [elpete](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/208#issuecomment-344917238) and [adamwathan](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/208#issuecomment-344918566).

I solved this problem by using normal CSS rules inside `@layer` directive. Not a good fix but it could be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
@layer components{
    .heroButton{
        @apply px-6 py-2 border border-[#242424] rounded-full uppercase text-xs tracking-widest text-gray-500 transition-all hover:border-[#F7AB0A]/40 hover:text-[#F7ABOA]/40
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my global.css but the console throws this error

[The error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywoEm.png)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33058222)

Answer (score 0):

This JIT grammer can only be used in class names

Comment: Hi there! Comment-like posts should stay in the comments section just under the question. If you think you have the answer, it is best when you provide more information and possibly back it up with sources. Following that convention will help users find the answers where they expect it the most.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Because you let the mode automatically rearrange the code when saving. Go to Settings, search for the phrase "formatonsave", remove the check mark and the code "hover: bg-gray-100" remove the space, the error is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved by adding the below code snippet in the vscode settings.json

```json
    "[css]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss",
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue caused by the IDE adding a space after the `:`, and we need to remove the space after the `:` to fix this issue.

You can try saving the file without the space and it'll work or you can try my approach.

### Previous code:

```
@layer components {
  .link {
    @apply cursor-pointer text-main-06 hover: underline;
  }
}
```

---

### Solution:

```
@layer components {
  .link {
    @apply cursor-pointer text-main-06;
  }

  .link:hover {
    @apply underline;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to resolve this error you should define a global var and then you can use it in you app.css file here the method of doing this

```
.btnPrimary {
    @apply py-3 px-8 font-semibold text-white rounded transition-all duration-300;
    background-color: var(--color-secondary); /* Change to the appropriate secondary color */
}

.btnPrimary:hover {
    background-color: var(--color-Primary); /* Change to the appropriate primary color */
}
```